# pyspark: pip install couldn't find a version

Tags: pip, pyspark

I am trying to install the `pyspark` using `pip install` like below. But I got the following errors.

```
(python_virenv)edamame$ pip install pyspark
Collecting pyspark
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspark (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyspark
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As of Spark 2.2, PySpark is now available in PyPI.

`pip install pyspark`

---

As of Spark 2.1, PySpark is pip installable but not yet from PyPI, which is under consideration for 2.2 in this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18128). To install PySpark you now just need download Spark 2.1+ and run setup.py:

```
cd spark-2.1/python/
pip install -e .
```

Big thanks to @Holden!

Answer (score 2):

`pyspark` is not in PyPI so you could not directly use `pip install` to install it.

Instead you could download a proper version of Spark here: http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html, and you will get a compressed TAR file. Then unpack it and `pyspark` is in its `python` folder.

To open the Python version of the Spark shell, you could go into your Spark directory and type:

```
bin/pyspark
```

or

```
bin\pyspark
```

in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`pyspark` doesn't even exist in PyPI as you can see from https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pyspark&submit=search, that's why `pip` is telling you it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

PySpark can be installed in the following ways.

Download spark from : [Spark Downloads](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

Download and extract the compressed file. Go to the **bin** folder, and execute

```
./bin/pyspark
```

You might want to add the bin folder in the `$PATH` variable of your shell as well.

Or,

You can install it from the CDH distribution :

- Add CDH keys following the steps here :
  http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html
- Install spark following the steps here :
  http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_spark_install.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba--6eed2fb8-14349d04bee--7ef8

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add it to my virtual env?

Comment: You should be able to. I am not sure if it would be particularly helpful though. You can refer to cloudera's link here :  http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-prepare-your-apache-hadoop-cluster-for-pyspark-jobs/